# How to use Autofac to inject ViewModels in a Windows Phone 8 application?

Tags: dependency-injection, viewmodel, windows-phone-8, viewmodellocator

I want to be able to inject ViewModels into the Views in my Windows Phone 8 application using Autofac as my IoC container. How do I go about doing this? I have looked at the Caliburn.Micro framework, but I'd like to use something simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisely for this purpose I have created a small demo application. It defines a `ViewModelLocator` class:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private readonly IContainer container;

    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<ItemViewModel>();

        this.container = containerBuilder.Build();
    }

    public MainViewModel MainViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public ItemViewModel ItemViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.container.Resolve<ItemViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

To use this class from your views, you have to add it to your application's resources. You do this by modifying the **Application.Resources** section in **App.xaml**:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:ViewModelLocator xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AutofacWP8DependencyInjectionDemo" x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now you will be able to inject the view model in the view. Just have the view point to the `DataContext`. To reference the `MainViewModel` as the `DataContext` simply add the following to your view:

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
```

You can see that it sets the `DataContext` to the `MainViewModel` property of the `ViewModelLocator` class, which uses **Autofac** to create the `MainViewModel` instance using dependency injection.

You can find the source here: https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/autofacwp8dependencyinjectiondemo.git

Comment: which is the best place for putting this IOC Autofac configuration in windows Phone 8 App like on which event(Launch or Active). What i'm thinking is we can put this things into Launch.Is it right ? or i need some code up-gradation.

Comment: Launch would be fine.

Comment: Just want to sure that is it going to create any issue while application is come from Tomb-stoned / dormant state ?